# Выбор 10 последних записей (по дате) сгруппированные по 2 полям MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Есть база данных сообщений со структурой

```
id       - ID
user_id  - ID отправившего сообщение
owner_id - ID получившего сообщение
text     - текст сообщения
created  - дата создания в формате Y-m-d H:i:s
```

Необходимо получить 10 последних записей из базы сгруппированные по 2 полям 
**user-id** и **owner-id** одновременно, отсортированные по дате.

Данные в базе:

```
id | user_id | owner_id | text               | created
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1  |    1    |     2    | Привет Коля        | 2000-01-01 00:00:01
2  |    2    |     1    | Здорова Кирилл     | 2000-01-01 00:00:02
3  |    2    |     1    | Как дела?          | 2000-01-01 00:00:03
4  |    1    |     3    | Привет Серега!     | 2000-01-01 00:00:04
5  |    3    |     1    | ООО Кирюха привет! | 2000-01-01 00:00:05
6  |    2    |     3    | От Коли - Сергею   | 2000-01-01 00:00:06
7  |    3    |     1    | Есть денег в долг? | 2000-01-01 00:00:07
8  |    1    |     4    | Ну что у нас?      | 2000-01-01 00:00:08
```

При выборке хочу получить вот такой результат:

```
id | user_id | owner_id | text               | created
-------------------------------------------------------------------
8  |    1    |     4    | Ну что у нас?      | 2000-01-01 00:00:08
7  |    3    |     1    | Есть денег в долг? | 2000-01-01 00:00:07
3  |    2    |     1    | Как дела?          | 2000-01-01 00:00:03
```

Как сделать?

(дата 1 января 2000 полночь - для наглядности)

Решение такое

```
'SELECT id, user_id, owner_id, text, created, (user_id + owner_id) uid
 FROM (SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY created DESC) AS msg
 WHERE user_id = :user_id OR owner_id = :user_id
 GROUP BY uid
 ORDER BY created DESC
 LIMIT :limit'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT id, user_id, owner_id, text, created
    FROM messages
GROUP BY user_id, owner_id
ORDER BY created DESC
   LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Если так сделать то SQL мне выдает все возможные варианты

user_id - owner_id

1 - 2
2 - 1
3 - 1
1 - 3

а надо чтобы в обе стороны уникальность была.
Как бы порядок owner_id  и user_id не должны иметь значения

Comment: Придумал как вывести уникальные значения обеих полей

Складываем owner_id и user_id получаем UID уникальный ID сообщений, группируем по UID получаем сообщения в Единственном экземпляре, но теперь суть в том что Группировка выбирает ПЕРВОЕ значение а надо ПОСЛЕДНИЕ

Comment: Ага. 1+4 и 2+3... Сейчас подумаю над первым пунктом. Теперь более понятно, чего именно вы хотели. 1 поле где user_id или owner_id = 1 - не очень очевидно из вопроса.

Comment: `'SELECT
    id, user_id, owner_id, text, created, (user_id + owner_id) uid
  FROM
    messages
  WHERE
    user_id = :user_id OR owner_id = :user_id
  GROUP BY uid
  ORDER BY created DESC
  LIMIT :limit'`

Группирую по UID но надо получить последнее сообщение